# call a method by a character variable in R5 class

Tags: r

I want to know how to call a method of a R5 Class object by using a character variable of the name of the method.
Say I have a R5 class object **Object.R5** and it has a method called **myMethod**. The usual way we call the method is just typing:

**Object.R5$myMethod()**

However if I set a variable

**method.name <- 'myMethod'**

I'm wondering how can I call the method by using **method.name**? I tried:

**do.call(paste("Object.R5$", method.name, "()", sep=""))**

But this prompt an error message saying *'what' must be a character string or a function*. I know the answer must be trivial but I'm new to R5 class so... anyone knows the answer please help.

Comment: .... and the people who teach this really dislike the R5 designation.

Comment: @DWin who are the "people who teach this"?

Comment: Well, John Chambers for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
get(method_name, envir=Object.R5)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this method is fine. However, this only works after I run Object.R5$myMethod() for once. Otherwise if I run get(method_name, envir=Object.R5) directly, it prompt the error message saying function 'myMethod' not found. Did I miss sth?

Comment: You said you had an object named "Object.R5".

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(parse(text=paste0('Object.R5$',method.name,'()')))
```

Comment: This definitely works! But it's not flexible in the sense that I cannot add arguments in the usual way (unless arguments are added in strings).